# PHP ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, php7.2

На одностраничном сайте(сайт для продаж) при попытке нажать кнопку "Оформить заказ" выскакивает ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in .../send.php on line 84
Сам код send.php:

```
<?php
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if(empty($phone)) {
?>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type"                 
content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Спасибо!</title>



</head>



<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); max-width: 
980px; min-width: 300px; width: auto; 
margin: 0px auto; background-color: rgb(255,                                 
255, 255); font-family: pt sans,arial;">
<br><br>
<center style="padding: 15px 30px; border: 
3px solid rgb(63, 63, 63); background-color: 
rgb(255, 161, 161);">
<h1 style="font-size: 1.4rem;">Вы не ввели 
необходимые данные!<br>
Вернитесь на сайт и заполните контакнутю 
форму.<br>
</h1></center><br><br>
<a style="display: inline-block;height: 
53px;height: 5.3rem;margin: 0px 0 
0px;padding: 0 24px; font-size: 1.8rem; 
letter- 
spacing: 0.02em; line-height: 53px; line- 
height: 5.3rem; text-align: center; text-                        
decoration: none; color: black; transition: 
background-color 0.2s ease-out 0s; border- 
radius: 7px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); -webkit-box- 
shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px 0px rgba(50, 50, 
50, 0.2); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 
0px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2); box-shadow: 
inset 0px -3px 0px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 
0.2); background: rgb(196, 255, 161); 
width:500px;margin:0 auto;display:block; 
border: 1px solid #ccc;" href="./" 
class='hover'>
Вернуться на сайт</a>
</body>
</html>
<?
}else {

$email2="example@gmail.com"; // ------------ 
----------------------------- почта, куда 
отправляем письмо
$headers  =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .=  'Content-type: text/html; 
charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .=  'To: <'.$email2.'>, '."\r\n";
$headers .=  'From: <site.ru>' . "\r\n"; // 
---------------------- адрес отправителя, 
это заголовок письма, менять не обязательно
$subject2    = "Название товара"; // ------- 
---------------------------------- заголовок
$message2    = "
<br>Имя: ".$_POST['name']."
<br>Телефон: ".$_POST['phone']."

<br>IP-адрес посетителя: 
".@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."
<br>Время заказа: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s').";
";
$mail=mail($email2, $subject2, $message2, 
$headers);
if($mail==true){
?>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" 
content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Спасибо!</title></head>
<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); max-width: 
980px; min-width: 300px; width: auto; 
margin: 0px auto; background-color: rgb(255, 
255, 255); font-family: pt sans,arial;">
<br><br>
<center style="padding: 15px 30px; border:     
3px solid rgb(63, 63, 63); background-color:         
rgb(196, 255, 161);">
<h1 style="font-size: 1.4rem;">Благодарим за     
Заявку!<br>
Ваша заявка принята и поставлена в     
обработку.<br>
Вы указали следующие данные для обратной связи:<br><hr>
Имя:
<?php
 echo $_POST['name'];
 ?><br>
 Телефон:
 <?php
 echo $_POST['phone'];
 ?>
</h1></center><br><br>
<a style="display: inline-block;height: 53px;height:     5.3rem;margin: 0px 0 0px;padding: 0 24px; font-size: 1.8rem;     letter-spacing: 0.02em; line-height: 53px; line-height:     5.3rem; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color:     black; transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out 0s; border-    radius: 7px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2); box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2); background: rgb(196, 255, 161); width:500px;margin:0 auto;display:block; border: 1px solid #ccc;" href="./" class='hover'>
Вернуться на сайт</a>
<!-- ниже код метрики (для отслеживания конверсии) -->

<!-- выше код метрики -->
<style>
.hover:hover {
background:#9FD083 !important;
transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}
</style>






</body>
</html>
<?
}else{
echo "no";
}
}
?>
```

Спасибо

Comment: Замените `<?` на `<?php`

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил. Всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на ваши комментарии, вот к примеру:

```
$email2="example@gmail.com"; // ------------ 
----------------------------- почта, куда 
отправляем письмо
```

здесь видно что вы закомментировали только `// ------------` это, нижние же строки остались без комментария, из-за этого и ошибка. Пройдитесь по всему коду и закомментируйте всё что требуется

Comment: В самом коде все нужные строки закомментированы. Я сделал ошибку, когда задавал вопрос на форум.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема возникла в похожем файле, скрипт успешно работал в PHP 5, а при переходе на PHP 7 стала появляться эта ошибка.

У меня были подозрения на такие участки кода:

> ?> HTML код <?php

.

Да, и когда я их заменил на

> echo 'HTML код';

ошибка исчезла.