# Parse Error syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ')' (0)

Tags: php

```
[ParseError] 
syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ')' (0)
/home/h/homonyly/homonyly.beget.tech/public_html/bitrix/templates/kitlisa-market/header.php:426
#0: require
    /home/h/homonyly/homonyly.beget.tech/public_html/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog.php:11
#1: require_once(string)
    /home/h/homonyly/homonyly.beget.tech/public_html/bitrix/header.php:1
#2: require(string)
    /home/h/homonyly/homonyly.beget.tech/public_html/index.php:2
```

Помогите исправить.

Участок кода, куда вносились правки:

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
use \Bitrix\Main\Localization\Loc;
Loc::loadLanguageFile(__FILE__);
define("SITE_SERVER_PROTOCOL", (CMain::IsHTTPS()) ? "https://" : "http://");
global $APPLICATION;

$curPage = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage();
$isMain = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false);
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?=LANGUAGE_ID?>">
<head>
<title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle()?></title>
<?$APPLICATION->ShowHead()?>

<?
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">');

//Favicons
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">');

//Apple metatags
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#009548">');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">');

//Microsoft meta
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#009548">');

$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/css/main.min.css' );
$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/css/colors.css' );
$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/css/custom.css' );
$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS(SITE_SERVER_PROTOCOL . SITE_SERVER_NAME .'/include/whatsapp/style.css' );
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/scripts.min.js" );
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/custom.js" );
?>
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle()?>">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=$APPLICATION->ShowProperty("description")?>">
<meta property="og:url" content="<?=SITE_SERVER_PROTOCOL . SITE_SERVER_NAME . $curPage?>">
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=SITE_SERVER_PROTOCOL . SITE_SERVER_NAME?><?$APPLICATION->IncludeFile( SITE_DIR.'include/logo.php', Array(), Array('SHOW_BORDER'=>false) );?>">


</head>
```

**Update**

Поставил сюда, проблема не ушла.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нельзя посмотреть в контроле версии (git/svn/...) что поменялось? Так-то вроде бы скобки на месте...

Comment: Прошу прощения, я нулевой в работе с кодами. Могу скинуть  полный код сайта, если это поможет решить проблему.

Comment: Судя по https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1012638/201445 у вас ошибка в `<?` замените его на `<?php`

Comment: Перед $APPLICATION, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, перед $APPLICATION

Comment: Кст, заметил, что `<?` и в других местах есть. Поменяйте все `<?` на `<?php`, в: `<?if`, `<?$APP...`, ...

Comment: @gil9red может ты посоветуешь весь битрикс переписать? Очевидно что короткие теги включены, иначе система б вообще не работала.

Comment: @u_mulder, как скажете, тогда, по вашему, в чем проблема у автора?

Comment: В целом я погорячился, приношу извинения. Возможно короткие теги отключены, и их надо включить, вместо переписывания битрикса, там такого шлака вагон. Просто меня смутило, что ОП сообщает, что он вносил изменения. Значит раньше работало и с короткими тегами.

Comment: @u_mulder, бывает :) Думаю, ваш комментарий насчет включения поддержки коротких тегов является хорошим ;)